# Can different PV be associated to same EFS volume in EKS

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, amazon-efs, kubernetes-pvc

Using aws-efs-csi-driver for efs provisioning in EKS

**Current Setup**
I have created a PV having EFS volume id that bound to pvc in a namespace(N1) wherein pods mounts this volume to read and write data to EFS

Scenario
Now create a another PV resource with volume id of same EFS, would it bind to PVC in some different namespace(N2) with same mount point ?

**To be concise following is my query--**

Can same EFS volume id be given in differnt PV's, which further bound to different PVC's in different namespaces ?

Comment: Did you read the docs and examples: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-efs-csi-driver/blob/master/examples/kubernetes/multiple_pods/README.md

Comment: This doesnt say anything about namespaces